# sprites are not visible during touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All Sprite not visible while moving one sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577193/all-sprite-not-visible-while-moving-one-sprite)

I am having 7 sprites in my scene.All the sprites are add to mutablearray. when i touch one sprite to move,other sprites not visible after my touches move method

here is my code

```
if( (self=[super init])) {

    sprites=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    CCLayer *base=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Base.png"];
    base.position=ccp(512,384);
    [self addChild:base];

    x=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
    {
        CCSprite *hole=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png"];
        hole.position=ccp(140+x,318);
        hole.tag=i;
    [self addChild:hole];
        hole.visible=YES;
        [sprites addObject:hole];
        x=x+75;
    }

    self.isTouchEnabled=YES;

}
return self;
}
```

My touchesmove method:

```
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
NSLog(@"count:%i",[sprites count]);
UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];
location=[self convertToNodeSpace:location];

for(CCSprite *s in sprites)
{
s.position=ccp(location.x,location.y);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to set all the sprite positions to be the same as your touch position. This would mean all sprites are covered up except the topmost one...

```
for(CCSprite *s in sprites)
{
   s.position=ccp(location.x,location.y);
}
```

Comment: I could'nt get you please help me with more code

Comment: your sprites occupy the same position

Comment: Simply removing the code I quoted above should probably solve the problem...