# All Sprite not visible while moving one sprite

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I am having 7 sprites in my scene.All the sprites are add to mutablearray. when i touch one sprite to move,other sprites not visible after my touches move method

here is my code

```
if( (self=[super init])) {

sprites=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

CCLayer *base=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Base.png"];
base.position=ccp(512,384);
[self addChild:base];

 x=0;
 for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
 {
    CCSprite *hole=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png"];
    hole.position=ccp(140+x,318);
    hole.tag=i;
 [self addChild:hole];
    hole.visible=YES;
    [sprites addObject:hole];
    x=x+75;
 }

self.isTouchEnabled=YES;

}
return self;
}


My touchesmove method:



-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
NSLog(@"count:%i",[sprites count]);
UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:[touch view]];
location=[[CCDirector sharedDirector]convertToGL:location];
location=[self convertToNodeSpace:location];

for(CCSprite *s in sprites)
{
s.position=ccp(location.x,location.y);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ccTouchesMoved` method, you are <s>moving</s> replacing `(1)` all your sprites ***together*** in the lines:

```
for(CCSprite *s in sprites)
{
    s.position=ccp(location.x,location.y);
}
```

In addition, I think your sprites are all of the same size so you are unable to differentiate whether it is one sprite or more.

---

In your `init` method, you should provide a tag to each sprite, and then modify it by its [tag](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html#a865a57d2fe81b5afa91a984f8cd3e986) in the `ccTouchesMoved` method.

In that method, you should know which sprite is being touched, and then act accordingly. Try defining a rectangle around `location`. Something like [this](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/3204#post-19804).

You might have to do something for the case when multiple sprites being touched. The most common thing to do is to perform actions on the sprite at the top (`z`) or decide by sprite `tag`s.

---

`(1)` To move your sprite(s) to some location, you should be using some [CCAction](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.0-rc/interface_c_c_action.html), most likely [CCMoveTo](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.9.0-beta/interface_c_c_move_to.html) and in some cases [CCMoveBy](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.2/interface_c_c_move_by.html).

Comment: I want to drag the sprite not to move

Comment: can you help me with code.

Comment: @Kentoh's answer link is a ready-made resource, and at code is at the end of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Your code in ccTouchesMoved moves all your sprites to one single touch location, so you are only seeing one sprite while the rest are actually stacked underneath.

If what you want to achieve is to simply drag sprites around upon touching, you need to test for intersection between the touch location and the bounding box of each sprite in ccTouchBegan. Once you have looped through and  found a sprite that is lying under your touch, you save a reference to it, and in ccTouchMoved, you translate that sprite's position along with the amount moved since the last time ccTouchMoved was called.

Check out Ray Wenderlich's tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2343/how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites-with-cocos2d

Comment: +1 for link addressing the exact issue.